# In i18next, is there an option to specify fallback for specific cases?

Tags: javascript, localization, i18next, fallback, react-i18next

When using the t function from i18next, is there a way to specify a fallback directly within the function call to achieve something like this:

```
entries.map( entry.label => 
    t(`page_name__${entry.label}__label`, fallback=entry.label)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out it is very simple to achieve that effect,

```
entries.map( entry.label => 
    t(`page_name__${entry.label}__label`, entry.label)
);
```

does the trick.